# Restrict number of parallel connections on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, iptables, ddos, malware

I'm on an Ubuntu server running Apache2. I would like to protect myself against (d)dos and syn flood attacks and therefore try to limit the number of parallel connections per client IP.

I've heard iptables can do this job, and I've had a look at different commands. I would like to hear your opinion.
As far as I know, the following commands both block clients for 60 seconds, if they make more than 100 concurrent/parallel connections to port 80. Is that correct, and is there any difference between the two?

**Command 1**

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 -j REJECT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 100 -m recent --set -j REJECT

**Command 2**

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 100 -j REJECT

#### My setup

I'm running multiple Wordpress sites on my server. I think 100 concurrent connections per client should be enough - anybody exceeding this should be blocked. Is this a reasonable limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to reconsider putting a reverse proxy (Lighttpd, Nginx, Varnish et. al.) in front of the Apache to ease the load on it in case of an attack.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Much appreciated!
Do you have any experience with Nginx? I've set it up in front of Apache and have faced a couple of challenges:

1) I currently have 10 vhost files for Apache. Do I have to duplicate all of them for Nginx?
2) I'm running a benchmark test on a file (test.php). If I change the content of the file, these changes are not reflected when viewing through Nginx. I know: the entire purpose of Nginx is caching static files, but shouldn't it purge cache when the file has changed?
Cheers!